# How can I prevent direct access to files using the .htaccess file?

Tags: html

I have a problem, I tried to restrict access to files with direct link (etc. [www.domen.com/folder/subfolder/file.ext](http://www.domen.com/folder/subfolder/file.ext)), to can only access to them using HTML code like "< img src ='/folder/subfolder/file.ext' >"...

I create .htaccess file with next lines

```
# enable mod_rewrite
RewriteEngine On
# RewriteCond = define rule condition
# HTTP_REFERER = check from where the request originated
# ! = exclude
# ^ = start of string
# [NC] = case insensitive search
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://domen.com/folder/subfolder [NC]
# \ = match any
# . = any character
# () = pattern, group
# $ = end of string
# [F] = forbidden, 403
# [L] = stop processing further rules
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|mp4|mov|mkv|flv)$ - [F,L]
```

Permission code of my files is 0644 in folders and subfolders, and permission code of my folders and subfolders is 0755

Problem is next.. When I use this code in .htaccess file I restrict direct access to files but at the same time I cant access them with HTML code..

```
<Directory platform/courses/*>
   Order Allow,Deny
   Allow from 1.1.1.1
   Deny from All
</Directory>
<Directory>
   Order Allow, Deny 
   Allow from All
</Directory>
```

I tried something like this (with IP addres taken from my cPanel) but I get this result: [image]

Comment: What is your folder structure?  I would put all such files in a subfolder.

Comment: I have posted a new answer which shows how to protect/hide the location of a file that can be downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

This is a cutdown version of what I use, so may have syntax errors.
The code is laid out to demonstrate the process. It can be made more robust.
The user is shown a url with a filename using **download.php**.
This can be posted.

Once the page is shown, it saves the filename with an expiry of 1 hour
in the cookie.  If it expires, the page has to be refreshed.

When the button is pressed, **sendfile.php** gets all the information
from the cookie, validates the expiry and filename and sends it.

### download.php

This is the landing page that the user can link to.

1. Show the user a link like **/download/document.pdf**
2. Use .htaccess to map it to **/download?name=document.pdf**

```php
<?php
// Returns the param by name, if not found then get it from the current_url.  
// So this works regardless of how the .htaccess redirection has been done.
function Get_Param ($name, $current_url)
{ $par = filter_var ($_GET [$name] ?? '', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  if ($par)
     {return $par;}
  if ($only)
     {return '';}
  $pi = pathinfo ($current_url);
  $pi = $pi['filename'] ?? '';
  if (strpos ($pi, '=') == 0)
     {return $pi;}
  else
     {return '';};
}

//Save Information in session with an expiry of 1hr
function Save_Info ($file)
{ $expiry = time()+3610;
  setcookie ('Download',$file, $expiry, '/');
}

//Get the Filename from the param or url
$file = Get_Param ('name', $current_url);
//Save to Session
Save_Info ($file)
// Show page with filename and details
// Show button with link "/sendfile"
?>
```

### sendfile.php

This basically pretends to be the file thats being downloaded and then dies.

```php
<?php
// Sends the file and dies
function Send_File ($file)
{ header ('Content-Description: File Transfer');
  header ('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
  header ('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
  header ('Expires: 0');
  header ('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
  header ('Pragma: public');
  header ('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
  flush ();
  if (readfile ($file)) {
      //LogIt ($file);
      }
  die ();
}

//Load Info from session and unset it
function Load_Info ()
{ $file = $_COOKIE ['Download'] ?? '';
  unset ($_COOKIE ['Download']);
  return $file
}

//Validate FileName
function Is_Valid ($file,$path)
{ if (!$file) {
     return 'FileName is Blank';
  }
  $file = urldecode($file);
  if (!preg_match('/^[^.][-a-z0-9_.]+[a-z]$/i', $file)) {
     return 'Invalid FileName';
     }
  if (!file_exists($path.$file)) {
     return 'File does not exist';
     }
  return false;
}

//Your actual path to the file
$path ='';
// Load Info from Session
$file = Load_Info ();
// Die if filename invalid or session expired
$error = Is_Valid ($file,$path);
if (!$error) {
    //Show Message and die
   }
else
   {Send_File ($path.$file);
   }
?>
```

Comment: Ok, I will try it tonight and I will notice you if I solve the problem, thank you!

Comment: If that worked for you, the protocol is to tick the answer and perhaps upvote it.